# explain " double value = Double.valueOf(fstNmElmntLst.item(k).getTextContent()); "

Tags: java

What does this statement do?

```
double value = Double.valueOf(fstNmElmntLst.item(k).getTextContent());
```

Comment: What part of that don't you understand?

Answer (score 3):

Quite a lot going on there...

- Gets the text content from some list as a string
- converts the string to a Double (object wrapper for primitive double)
- unboxes the Double to a primitive double

We could break it down

```
String tmp = fstNmElmntLst.item(k).getTextContent(); // fetch some string
Double wrapper = Double.valueOf(tmp); // convert (parse string to a number)
double value = wrapper; // unbox
```

A more efficient way to do this would be to use the parseDouble utility function. This avoids an unnecessary intermediate object being created:

```
double value = Double.parseDouble(fstNmElmntLst.item(k).getTextContent());
```

If you're new to java, have a look at some starter tutorials on the oracle.com site, for example [Number Classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberclasses.html) tutorial. If you're ever unsure of a behaviour of particular function just look at the javadocs. Just google something like "Double.valueOf javadoc 6" or setup your IDE properly.

Here's the javadoc for [Double.valueOf(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29). It will give you the full info on expected inputs, outputs, and other useful info like exceptions, in this case the NumberFormatException, which is thrown if your text can't be interrupted  as a number.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently `getTextContent` returns `String`. The typical way to convert `String` to `double` is to use the `valueOf` method in the class `Double`. As one can convert from `Double` to the primitive type `double`, the way to convert a `String` to `double` is to pass the string to `valueOf` in `Double`.

Answer (score 0):

It takes a text content of an item with index `k` from some kind of list `fstNmElmntLst` and parses that text as a `double` value.

Answer (score 0):

This is casting from string to double because of array element, but there should be array value numeric else exception will raise.